# MathJax glitch when viewing comment

Tags: bug, mathjax

Several of the answers to [this question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/26226/://) use MathJax, and everything displays fine. However, I got a notification about a comment, and when I follow [this link](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/26226/concentrating-tokens-on-an-infinite-board/26234?noredirect=1#comment80729_26234) to the comment, the MathJax gets jumbled. The jumbling doesn't happen every time; if I reload the page several times, about half the time the MathJax displays fine. Here is a screen capture:
[image]

Comment: it happens with me too and not only on Puzzling SE but also on math and physics and chemistry...if it happens with all the people then maybe Puzzling meta is not the right place for this post. You should consider posting it on [Main Meta of stack exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @Julian if this is recent, then try cleaning your browser cache. We pushed a new release of MathJax yesterday.

Comment: @manshu - why? Stack Exchange developers monitor all metas.

Comment: @Oded i didn't knew it...I thought these kind of issues which are related to all the sites of SE must be placed there... Thanks for the info. and clarification.

Comment: @manshu - things that require the larger community discussion do benefit from going to MSE (discussion, feature requests that do pertain to all SE sites). Bug reports - no so much :)

Comment: @Peter I cleared the browser cache, but the issue persists.

Comment: I'll add that I experience this issue with Chrome, but eveything displays correctly in Safari

Comment: @Julian hm... Chrome sometimes requires a restart to really clear the cache. Did you happen to do one?

Comment: @Peter I did a restart, still the same issue

Comment: Thanks, @Julian. It was a long shot.  Could you post what MathJax about info from the MathJax menu says?

Comment: @Peter MathJax v2.6.1 using web TeX fonts, MathJax.js v2.6.1, TeX Input Jax v2.6.1, HTML-CSS Output Jax v2.6.1, PreviewHTML Output Jax v2.6.1, mml Element Jax v2.6.0, AssistiveMML Extension v2.6.1, MathEvents Extension v2.6.0, MathMenu Extension v2.6.1, MathZoom Extension v2.6.0, TeX/AMSmath Extension v2.6.1, TeX/AMSsymbols Extension v2.6.0, TeX/noErrors Extension v2.6.0, TeX/noUndefined Extension v2.6.0, fast-preview Extension v2.6.0, tex2jax Extension v2.6.0, Chrome v48.0.2564.103 — woff or otf fonts

Comment: Thanks, @Jullian. Nothing suspicious in there; sigh. Do you have any extensions or bookmarklets running? What OS are you using?

Comment: @Peter I disabled all my extensions and restarted, the issue persists. No bookmarklets. I see this on Windows 7 and Mac OSX 10.10.

Comment: @JulianRosen Ok I'm running out of ideas. FWIW, I can't reproduce this Windows 7 (Chrome, though v48.0.2564.97m but I'm guessing that's close enough) or on OSX 10.10 (though I can only test 49 and 50 there and not with TeX fonts). It seems like a Frankenbug.

Comment: Ok, now I see a problem on Windows 7 but it's different from what you reported (there's an actual error in the javascript console). I'll look into ti.

Comment: @Julian does it help to switch the output to CommonHTML or SVG output?

Comment: Ok, after disabling the FastPreview I see the same problem on Win7. I've started a report at https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/issues/1384

Comment: It seems this only affects the HTML-CSS and FastPreview output so switching to CommonHTML or SVG output should help.

Comment: @JulianRosen it's starting to look like a problem related to StackExchange's integration of MathJax (see the issue for more details). Do you see problems on other SE sites?

Comment: @Peter Yes, I found a similar issue on MO. [The question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/226896/maximal-trivialising-subspace-for-a-vector-bundle) shows up fine, [the link to the comment](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/226896/maximal-trivialising-subspace-for-a-vector-bundle?noredirect=1#comment560897_226896) is jumbled about half the time.

Comment: OK. We've reached to StackOverflow about the issue. But other outputs should work in the mean time, I hope.

Comment: This is the same issue as reported in [math.se](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/275997/mathjax-preview-bug-seems-to-be-neglected) and there are instructions for reproducing there.  It is related to the fact that during editing, the DOM is removed before MathJax has completed typesetting.  I am working on a solution.  In the meantime, turning off fast-preview (in the MathJax contextual menu) may help.